# Cannot find HTC One in ADB, SD card not mounted, incorrect kernel for installed ROM, no backup

Tags: adb, rom, kernel

Pretty much what the title says. I have messed up big time. Because I am switching carriers, I have to switch back to the stock ROM. It is stuck at the loading screen, most likely because of a kernel issue. My stupid self didn't remember to make a backup.

Because of this, all I have access to is the boot loader. I cannot side load anything because ADB does not recognize my device.

I am in the biggest pickle I've ever been in with electronics. Anyone who can fix this is going to win the entire internet.

Comment: Which recovery are you using?

Comment: Somehow I have messed up my Recovery. Now the only thing I have access to is the bootloader/fastboot.

Answer (score 0):

If using TWRP you can sideload from within recovery.

1. Boot into TWRP.
2. Go to `Advanced > ADB Sideload` and slide to start.
3. Plug USB cable into PC.
4. If your device is not detected, manually add standard Google driver.
5. Then type `adb devices` and you should see: `xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx        sideload`
6. Type `adb sideload <filename.zip>` and it will be flashed automatically.

Comment: I can't even access CWM recovery right now.

Comment: I recommend you download latest TWRP img file for your device, reboot into fastboot, and flash with `fastboot flash recovery openrecovery-twrp-2.7.0.1-xxxxxxxx.img`, then follow instructions in answer.

Comment: C:\SDK\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140321\sdk\platform-tools>fastboot flash reco
very TWRP.img
target reported max download size of 1509371904 bytes
sending 'recovery' (9834 KB)...
OKAY [  1.248s]
writing 'recovery'...
(bootloader) signature checking...
FAILED (remote: signature verify fail)
finished. total time: 2.219s

When I try and load recovery, it opens the bootloader again.

Comment: You probably relocked your phone and you will need to unlock bootloader again to flash another rom. Is your goal to be stock/unlocked/rooted? or stock/locked? If your goal is to be 100% stock with locked bootloader, go [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2358738) and read this thread **very carefully**.

Comment: Before I can follow that thread, I need a way to get s-off through fastboot, still can't get ADB to work. I wasn't kidding when I said I was in a pickle. 

If I dug myself into a hole I cant crawl out of, so be it. I don't want to waste too much time of kind strangers. Is it FUBAR?

Comment: I don't think your phone is hard bricked, however troubleshooting this goes a bit beyond the scope of the format here. I recommend you join the [xda forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/) and ask for help there. Good luck.